# Solr DataImportHandler not found

Tags: tomcat, configuration, solr, dataimporthandler

I am using  [Solr 3.3.0](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/solr/) with Tomcat 6.0.26. I was able to successfully install Solr and i was even able to access its web interface using http:/localhost:8084/solr/admin.

Now i want to use its dataimporthandler to index data from my database.I have added following to my solrconfig:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImport
 Handler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I have also created a data-config.xml in same directory.

My solrconfig file has following location for dataimport

```
  <lib dir="../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
```

And i have checked that dataimporthandler.jar file exist in the dist folder at following path C:\web\solr\example\lib\apache-solr-3.3.0\dist

But whenever I type http:/localhost:8084/solr/dataimport or http:/localhost:8084/solr/admin/dataimport it says resource unavailable. I thought it was dur to some problem with Tomcat setting so i stopped tomcat and tried to start Solr from cmd using java -jar start.jar. And i get the following error

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:
Severe errors in solr configuration.
Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.
If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: 

<abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError>

in solr.xml

-------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class    
    'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler'
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:389)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:423)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:459)
at  
  org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:157)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:563)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:463)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:207)
at 
   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:130)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at 
 org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart
 (ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   
  org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:373)
... 34 more
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've been looking at this problem for a bit on my own, using solr 4.1 and tomcat.  I wasn't able to include the library I needed with `<lib dir="../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" /> -->`, which I figured had to be correct because from the directory that I had the solrconfig.xml in, it was two directories up and one down to dist.  It wasn't until I temporarily subbed in the direct path (for me, /opt/solr/dist) that I realized that the problem was that I was starting from the wrong directory.  It turns out that what I needed was:

```
<lib dir="../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" /> -->
```

So, if you're having trouble with including this, check that you're starting from the directory that contains your conf directory, and not the conf directory itself.

Comment: I am using Solr 4.2.1. I have both the mysql connector and data import jars under `project-dir/solr/lib` and added to the project build path. `solrconfig.xml` is under `project-dir/solr/app-cores/SimilarList/conf/solrconfig.xml`. I tried `<lib dir="../../lib" />` which does not work. `../lib`, `../../../lib` and even the complete path `C:/Users/Arun/workspace/project-dir/solr/lib` don't work! I am getting the same class not found exception!

Comment: When Solr starts it says ProjectClassLoader loaded these jars along with the ones found under `webapp/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Also the start-up log says: SolrResourceLoader replaceClassLoader loaded these jars!

Answer (score 6):

It seems that for several versions of Solr including 4.3, the dataimport handler jar is not included in the final war file when you build from source.

There is a very simple fix to this by modifying the file /solr/webapp/build.xml.

1. Open that file and find the "dist" target.
2. Find this section of the "dist" target:

   `<lib dir="${dist}" excludes="${exclude.from.war},${common.classpath.excludes}">`
3. Add this item to the list of includes in that section:

   `<include name="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-${version}.jar" />`

Save and exit.

Now, when you build, do the following:

- ant dist-contrib
- ant dist

To verify that the dataimporthandler jars are in your WAR file, unpack it, and look for it among the jars in the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Some variation of this will probably work for earlier versions too.

Answer (score 4):

The jar you are looking for (at least in 3.5) is under the ./dists folder

Answer (score 3):

As far as you are telling us, your jar file name does not match the supplied regexp:

With the given configuration:

```
<lib dir="../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
```

The file:

```
dataimporthandler.jar
```

Does not match the regexp, while it has to, as shown in the [sample configuration file for Solr](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml)

Probably start by just specifying:

```
<lib dir="../../dist/"/>
```

Comment: I wrote it in short, my jar file name is "apache-solr-dataimporthandler-3.3.0.jar"

Answer (score 2):

i put solr jars under WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have following three required fields correct.

1)  A entry for dataimport handler in solr-conf.xml

```
</requestHandler>
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

2) Your Solr war file is aware of solr-home folder , and hence the libraries included in solr-home. If solr-home is added explicitly.

## To make your solr.war aware of solr-home folder deploy the solr.war at server.

## Go to apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/solr/WEB-INF and open web.xml in any text editor.

## Now search for the entry showing below

```
<!-- <env-entry>
<env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
<env-entry-value> /Path/To/My/solr/Home/solr/</env-entry-value>
<env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry> -->
```

## replace  value to the solr-home folder in your case. This will make solr, point solr-home folder hence lib folder inside it.

3) Add your new libraries location to /home/javaguys/solr-home/collection1/conf/solr-config.xml.  just under   tag like .

This will solve your problem i hope, for more information please check out this [solution here.](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/01/if-you-want-to-configure-solr4_19.html)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by building dataimporthandler jar from the solr source. For 3.1, dataimporthandler is not included in apache-solr-core-3.1.0.jar . I couldn't find the jar file for dataimporthandler, so I built it from the source and put it in my solr lib directory

Answer (score 1):

I am using Solr 4.0 with a Glassfish 3.1.2 container and I solved the problem by opening the solr war itself, manually just adding the jar files inside, and redeploying glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem twice, on Windows Tomcat, and Ubuntu Tomcat.

SOLR 4.3, and Tomcat 7

Make sure that the file below is in the SOLR_Home /lib folder

solr-dataimporthandler-4.3.0.jar

As mentioned above you also need the reference in the config file.  Adjust the path as needed.

`<lib dir="../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />`

I might have some paths messed up, but that is how I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The version is 4.3.1, I copied the `dataimporthandler` jar to `/lib` but it didn't work. I added this to `conf/solrconfig.xml` to fix this problem.

```xml
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below code in your solrconfig.xml file under the config tag.
Note: Please change the version of jar files accordingly.

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar" />
```

For more information you can refer [connecting-solr-to-database](http://geekdirt.com/blog/connecting-solr-to-database/) .