# Solr 4.1 DataImportHandler ClassNotFoundException

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I have been trying to setup Data Import Handler (Solr 4.1) following [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) tutorial and tried solutions suggested in previous posts such as [Configure DIH in multicore solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225650/configure-dih-in-multicore-solr)  and added the dataimport jar to the classpath but the error still persists. Any methods to solve this?

Here is the entire exception stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Unable to create core: collection1
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:794)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:607)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:1003)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:1033)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$3.call(CoreContainer.java:629)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$3.call(CoreContainer.java:624)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:168)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:731)
... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler'
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:438)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:507)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:581)
at    org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:154)
... 14 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:627)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:422)
... 17 more
Feb 12, 2013 12:37:47 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core: collection1
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.recordAndThrow(CoreContainer.java:1654)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:1039)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$3.call(CoreContainer.java:629)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$3.call(CoreContainer.java:624)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:794)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:607)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:1003)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:1033)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
at      org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:168)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:731)
... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler'
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:438)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:507)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:581)
at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:154)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:627)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:422)
... 17 more
```

Solrconfig.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <config>
    <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_41</luceneMatchVersion>
    <lib dir="../../../contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
    <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />
    <lib dir="../../../contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
    <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />
    <lib dir="../../../contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
    <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />
    <lib dir="../../../contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
    <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />
    <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-4.1.0.jar\d.*\.jar" />
    <lib dir="../../lib/" regex=".*\.jar" /> 
    <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>
    <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" 
        class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory}"/> 
    <indexConfig>
    </indexConfig>
    <jmx />
    <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
        <updateLog>
            <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
        </updateLog>
        <autoCommit> 
            <maxTime>15000</maxTime> 
            <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
        </autoCommit>
    </updateHandler>
    <query>
        <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>
        <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
            size="512"
            initialSize="512"
            autowarmCount="0"/>
        <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
            size="512"
            initialSize="512"
            autowarmCount="0"/>
        <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
            size="512"
            initialSize="512"
            autowarmCount="0"/>
        <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>
        <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>
        <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>
        <listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
            <arr name="queries">
            </arr>
        </listener>
        <listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
            <arr name="queries">
                <lst>
                    <str name="q">static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml</str>
                </lst>
            </arr>
        </listener>
        <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>
        <maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>
    </query>
    <requestDispatcher handleSelect="false" >
        <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true" 
            multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"
            formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"/>
        <httpCaching never304="true" />
    </requestDispatcher>
    <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
            <int name="rows">10</int>
            <str name="df">app_data</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>
    <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="echoParams">all</str>
            <str name="wt">xml</str>
            <str name="indent">true</str>
            <str name="df">app_data</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
            <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>       
            <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
            <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
            <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>         
        </lst>
        <arr name="last-components">
            <str>spellcheck</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
    <requestHandler name="/get" class="solr.RealTimeGetHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="omitHeader">true</str>
            <str name="wt">json</str>
            <str name="indent">true</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>
    <requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    </requestHandler>
    <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
    </requestHandler>
    <requestHandler name="/update/json" class="solr.JsonUpdateRequestHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="stream.contentType">application/json</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>
    <requestHandler name="/update/csv" class="solr.CSVRequestHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="stream.contentType">application/csv</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>
    <requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
        startup="lazy"
        class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="lowernames">true</str>
            <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>
            <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
            <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
            <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>
    <requestHandler name="/analysis/field" 
        startup="lazy"
        class="solr.FieldAnalysisRequestHandler" />
    <requestHandler name="/analysis/document" 
        class="solr.DocumentAnalysisRequestHandler" 
        startup="lazy" />
    <requestHandler name="/admin/" 
        class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
    <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
        <lst name="invariants">
            <str name="q">solrpingquery</str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="echoParams">all</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>
    <requestHandler name="/debug/dump" class="solr.DumpRequestHandler" >
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="echoParams">explicit</str> 
            <str name="echoHandler">true</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>
    <requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" > 
    </requestHandler>
    <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
        <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">default</str>
            <str name="field">keyword</str>
            <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
            <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
            <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
            <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
            <int name="minPrefix">0</int>
            <int name="maxInspections">10</int>
            <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
            <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.02</float><!--appears in more than 2% of the documents its assumed to be correct, and no suggestions are given, I don't think use of this parameter makes any sense since dictionary is based on keyword field which is unique. Not sure if frequency is also based on that column only.-->
        </lst>
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
            <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>      
            <str name="field">keyword</str>
            <str name="combineWords">true</str>
            <str name="breakWords">true</str>
            <int name="maxChanges">10</int>
        </lst>
    </searchComponent>
    <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="df">app_data</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
            <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>       
            <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
            <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
            <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>         
        </lst>
        <arr name="last-components">
            <str>spellcheck</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
    <searchComponent name="tvComponent" class="solr.TermVectorComponent"/>
    <requestHandler name="/tvrh" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="df">app_data</str>
            <bool name="tv">true</bool>
        </lst>
        <arr name="last-components">
            <str>tvComponent</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
    <searchComponent name="clustering"
        enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
        class="solr.clustering.ClusteringComponent" >
        <lst name="engine">
            <str name="name">default</str>
            <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.lingo.LingoClusteringAlgorithm</str>
            <str name="LingoClusteringAlgorithm.desiredClusterCountBase">20</str>
            <str name="carrot.lexicalResourcesDir">clustering/carrot2</str>
            <str name="MultilingualClustering.defaultLanguage">ENGLISH</str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="engine">
            <str name="name">stc</str>
            <str name="carrot.algorithm">org.carrot2.clustering.stc.STCClusteringAlgorithm</str>
        </lst>
    </searchComponent>
    <requestHandler name="/clustering"
        startup="lazy"
        enable="${solr.clustering.enabled:false}"
        class="solr.SearchHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <bool name="clustering">true</bool>
            <str name="clustering.engine">default</str>
            <bool name="clustering.results">true</bool>
            <str name="carrot.title">name</str>
            <str name="carrot.url">id</str>
            <str name="carrot.snippet">features</str>
            <bool name="carrot.produceSummary">true</bool>
            <bool name="carrot.outputSubClusters">false</bool>
            <str name="defType">edismax</str>
            <str name="qf">
                app_data
            </str>
            <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
            <str name="rows">10</str>
            <str name="fl">*</str>
        </lst>     
        <arr name="last-components">
            <str>clustering</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
    <searchComponent name="terms" class="solr.TermsComponent"/>
    <requestHandler name="/terms" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <bool name="terms">true</bool>
            <bool name="distrib">false</bool>
        </lst>     
        <arr name="components">
            <str>terms</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
    <searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
        <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
        <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
    </searchComponent>
    <requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
            <str name="df">app_data</str>
        </lst>
        <arr name="last-components">
            <str>elevator</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
      <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">/Users/username/data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
    <searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
        <highlighting>
            <fragmenter name="gap" 
                default="true"
                class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
                <lst name="defaults">
                    <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int>
                </lst>
            </fragmenter>
            <fragmenter name="regex" 
                class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">
                <lst name="defaults">
                    <int name="hl.fragsize">70</int>
                    <float name="hl.regex.slop">0.5</float>
                    <str name="hl.regex.pattern">[-\w ,/\n\&quot;&apos;]{20,200}</str>
                </lst>
            </fragmenter>
            <formatter name="html" 
                default="true"
                class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
                <lst name="defaults">
                    <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em>]]></str>
                        <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
                </lst>
            </formatter>
            <encoder name="html" 
                class="solr.highlight.HtmlEncoder" />
            <fragListBuilder name="simple" 
                class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragListBuilder"/>
            <fragListBuilder name="single" 
                class="solr.highlight.SingleFragListBuilder"/>
            <fragListBuilder name="weighted" 
                default="true"
                class="solr.highlight.WeightedFragListBuilder"/>
            <fragmentsBuilder name="default" 
                default="true"
                class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
            </fragmentsBuilder>
            <fragmentsBuilder name="colored" 
                class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
                <lst name="defaults">
                    <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[
                        <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">,
                                <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b style="background:magenta">,
                                        <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">,
                                                <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">,
                                                        <b style="background:lime">,<b style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str>
                                                            <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str>
                                                    </lst>
                                                </fragmentsBuilder>
                                                <boundaryScanner name="default" 
                                                    default="true"
                                                    class="solr.highlight.SimpleBoundaryScanner">
                                                    <lst name="defaults">
                                                        <str name="hl.bs.maxScan">10</str>
                                                        <str name="hl.bs.chars">.,!? &#9;&#10;&#13;</str>
                                                    </lst>
                                                </boundaryScanner>
                                                <boundaryScanner name="breakIterator" 
                                                    class="solr.highlight.BreakIteratorBoundaryScanner">
                                                    <lst name="defaults">
                                                        <str name="hl.bs.type">WORD</str>
                                                        <str name="hl.bs.language">en</str>
                                                        <str name="hl.bs.country">US</str>
                                                    </lst>
                                                </boundaryScanner>
                                            </highlighting>
                                        </searchComponent>
                                        <queryResponseWriter name="json" class="solr.JSONResponseWriter">
                                            <str name="content-type">text/plain; charset=UTF-8</str>
                                        </queryResponseWriter>
                                        <queryResponseWriter name="velocity" class="solr.VelocityResponseWriter" startup="lazy"/>
                                        <queryResponseWriter name="xslt" class="solr.XSLTResponseWriter">
                                            <int name="xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds">5</int>
                                        </queryResponseWriter>
                                        <admin>
                                            <defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>
                                        </admin>
                                    </config>
```

Comment: have you added the entry for dataimport jars in solrconfig.xml or included the jars in shared lib ?

Comment: @Jayendra Yes, I have done that

Comment: can you post your config ?

Comment: @Jayendra posted it as an edit

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best way to handle any class not found issue is to grab the required jars and put them in `solr/lib` dir, where the solr dir is same that contains solr.xml used to configure solr cores
you will also need to add following line to solrconfig.xml

```
<lib dir="../lib" />
```

This will load all required libs for all cores on your solr installation.

If you need to restrict the jar to a core then put it int

`instanceDir/lib` , no configuration is required for solrconfig.xml in this case.

for data import handler to work, you will need the JDBC jar also as well as `dist/solr-dataimporthandler-*.jar` to be put into the lib dir that you configure

Comment: Thx for your clear answer. I tried it, but it is not working in Solr 4.2.1. I have both mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar  and solr-dataimporthandler-4.2.1.jar under `solr/lib` and got `<lib dir="../../lib" />` in solrconfig.xml and still seeing the same error. Even tried giving the absolute path for the lib dir and it still doesn't work!

Comment: solrconfig should have <lib dir="../lib" /> not <lib dir="../../lib" />

Comment: In my case, solrconfig.xml is under `project-dir/solr/app-cores/SimilarList/conf/solrconfig.xml` and lib dir is at `project-dir/solr/lib` so relative to solrconfig.xml the lib dir is actually at `../../../lib`. But I read John Fiala's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934411/solr-dataimporthandler-not-found which suggests using the parent dir of solrconfig.xml, so that would be `../../lib` right?

Comment: You have to understand that the path is relative to solr.home .

Comment: Thx for helping me out. I see this when I start jetty: `INFO: solr home defaulted to 'solr/' (could not find system property or JNDI)` and I tried using `<lib dir="lib" regex=".*\.jar"/>`. I see this too: `INFO: Adding 'file:/C:/Users/Arun/workspace/solr-application-cores-4.2.1/solr/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar' to classloader`. Still no success.

Comment: Ok, the problem was that solrcore.properties where we got the driver, DB properties is not being read after upgrading to Solr 4.2. Once I hard-coded the values for driver, host, port, user and password in data-config.xml it is working fine.

Comment: And about the location of the JAR files, as long as they are under `solr/lib`, you do not need to add any lib definition in your solrconfig.xml. Else you can keep them under `webapp/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: placing jars in solr/lib and omitting lib def in solrconfig.xml worked for me as well

Answer (score 2):

Add lib folder in your Solr Core directory and add the required lib jar file into this. In this case you do not need to specify lib path in solrconfig.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

I just started trying to get Solr 4.1 working with MySQL today and encountered the exact same problem as you.

I managed to solve it by doing the following:

1. Commented out all the default LIB directories except for one:

   `<lib dir="../../../contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
       <!--
       <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />
       <lib dir="../../../contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
       <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />
       <lib dir="../../../contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
       <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />
       <lib dir="../../../contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
       <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />
       -->`
2. Grabbed the latest [mysql connector jar](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=412054)r file and [solr dataimporthandler jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-dataimporthandler/4.1.0)
3. Placed them in the remaining directory.

Started the server again and it worked.

This is on Windows 8 X86_64.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

In solr 4.1.0 add the following jar files in the project.
solr-dataimporthandler-4.1.0,
solr-dataimporthandler-extras-4.1.0

Execute it again.It will work.

Comment: what do you mean by "the project", where should it be put?

Comment: @Revathygs: Can you please clarify where we need to add this jar..
because even if we put in commom lib folder error is still there. and if we add it in solr/lib then also its giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer certainly works (which pretty much boils down to "copy everything to `$instancedir/lib`") but solr configuration provides a way to separate the "standard/global" libraries that comes with solr and "extension" libraries (i.e., custom solr handlers/parsers/etc) that's specific to the instance.

there are at least two directories that solr looks into to load classes needs to load: the `${solr.install.dir}` which is pretty much where solr is installed. use the scripts (available in v4.10.x) this is set by default to the directory where `bin/solr` script is run.  `solrconfig.xml` uses this directory as the base for loading the jars specified in the `solrconfig.xml` file; it can be overriden by a java `-D` parameter or overriding completely in the file itself as specified in the selected answer.  this is i would think one would have to load the "global" libraries.

now, there's a 2nd solr variable `${solr.solr.home}` which is the instance home where all the index artifacts/files are created, and here we have `solr.xml`.  you have this directory for each solr instance (running in a different port) separately.  in that `solr.xml` file, you can have a [`sharedLib`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%204.4%20and%20beyond) element, which is a folder relative `${solr.solr.home}`.  this is i would think any "extension" libraries specific to a solr instance will be loaded from.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception .add solr-dataimporthandler-extras-4.7.2.jar and solr-dataimporthandler-4.7.2.jar in your core's lib folder. This worked for me .