# HTTP error 500: Severe errors in solr configuration.Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dih

When i tried to import data from mysql table using DIH i got this error.

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/dataimport. Reason:

    Severe errors in solr configuration.

Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.

If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: 



    <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError>

in solr.xml

    org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler'
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:389)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:425)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:461)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:157)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:565)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:463)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:316)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:133)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:94)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:373)
        ... 33 more
```

Here is my schema.xml code

```
<fields>
    <field name="brands_test_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="categories_test_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
  </fields>
```

And the data-config.xml has this code:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
                driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/Webpage"      
                user="test" 
                password="test123"/>
    <document name="Products">
        <entity name="products" query="select brands_test_id,categories_test_id from products"
            <field name="brands_test_id" column="brands_test_id"
            <field name="categories_test_id" column="categories_test_id"
            <entity name="brands_test" query="select name from brands_test where id='$products.brands_test_id' "
                    <field name="brands_test" column="brands_test"/>
            </entity>
            <entity name="categories_test" query="select name from categories_test where id='$products.categories_test_id' "
                    <field name="categories_test" column="categories_test"/>
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Here is the solrconfig.xml file

```
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />

<requestHandler name="/dataimport"           class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

I downloaded mysql-connector-java-3.1.14.tar.gz and extracted it and copied to lib directory. Ami defining the file directory properly? Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is not related to your code, it is just the fact that Solr does not explicitly bundle the DIH jar(s) in the main web application archive anymore.  Fortunately it is easily overcome, see this: [Solr 4.1 DataImportHandler ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827375/solr-4-1-dataimporthandler-classnotfoundexception)