# Import PostgreSQL Database to Solr in Windows 7

Tags: windows, postgresql, solr, import, dih

I'm trying to import a PostgreSQL database to Solr 4.3.1, so far I added this code to Solrconfig.xml :

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

and this to the newly created db-data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
     url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"
     user="postgres"
     password="123" />
  <document>
    <entity name="phonebook" query="SELECT phone, firstname from phonebook">
      <field column="phone" name="id" />
      <field column="firstname" name="name" />
      <entity name="revision" query="select rev_id from revision where rev_page=${phonebook.phone}">
        <entity name="pagecontent" query="select old_text from pagecontent where old_id=${revision.rev_id}">
          <field column="old_text" name="text" />
        </entity>
      </entity>
   </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

all these files are under the collection1 directory, am I doing anything wrong ?

Edit:

when I connect using localhost:435/solr/TEST/dataimport

I get this error

```
    {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: RequestHandler init failure,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: RequestHandler init failure
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:1212)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:248)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:821)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:618)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:949)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:984)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$2.call(CoreContainer.java:597)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$2.call(CoreContainer.java:592)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: RequestHandler init failure
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:168)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:758)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:464)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:396)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInstance(SolrCore.java:518)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createRequestHandler(SolrCore.java:592)
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers.initHandlersFromConfig(RequestHandlers.java:154)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:789)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:448)
    ... 18 more
,code=500}
```

Comment: Are you actually getting any error messages when you try and import?

Comment: Yes when I connect using http://localhost:435/solr/TEST/dataimport I get this error Problem accessing /solr/TEST/dataimport. Reason:
 {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: RequestHandler init failure,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: RequestHandler init failure
 at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:1212)


and it's a long error

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler` - you need to add the DataImportHandler to the classpath. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934411/solr-dataimporthandler-not-found

Comment: Check out http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk and look for the article to set up the data import handler

Comment: @Allan Macmillan I followed exactly what you wrote in your blog but I still get the same error !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include DIH jars in your solrconfig.xml.
smth like this:

```
<lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar"/>
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar"/>
```

Comment: @condit ok I found the DIH jar file where should I put it, in Main solr file (C:\BitNami\solr-4.3.1-1\java\lib) or this one (C:\BitNami\solr-4.3.1-1\apache-solr\lib) ?

Comment: Thanks guys and especially @Allan Macmillan, it's working now like a charm :)